# Retornar dados de uma consulta sem determinados campos

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Bom dia, fiz uma consulta que retorna apenas dados concluídos entre um período informado, preciso apenas desses dois dados porém o entityframework está exigindo alguns campos que não preciso como ID. Existe alguma forma de ignorar esses dados e retornar apenas a minha consulta?

Código:

```
try
        {
            var year = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
            var dataInicial = year + "-01-01";
            var dataFinal = year + "-12-31";

            string sql = "";
            sql += " SELECT distinct Concluido Concluidos, count(Concluido) Total" +
                " WHERE DataInicio BETWEEN " + "'" + dataInicial + "' AND " + "'" + dataFinal + "' group by concluido;";

            
            var p = await context.Projetos
                     .FromSqlRaw(sql)
                     .AsNoTracking()
                     .ToListAsync();
            return Ok(p);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Falha: " + ex.ToString());
        }
```

Nenhum dos campos retorna na consulta existe na tabela, queria retornar os dados igual ao da consulta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei um código postado no stackoverflow mas postado diretamente no site entity framework core que pode te ajudar com o que precisa!

https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/51678809/can-entity-framework-core-run-sqlquery-

Ele indica que talvez que voce pode executar uma consulta através de componentes comandos e escreveram uma função que pode ser acoplada a seu código.

```cs
public static List<T> RawSqlQuery<T>(string query, Func<DbDataReader, T> map)
{
    using (var context = new DbContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder().Options)
    {
        using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            context.Database.OpenConnection();

            using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var entities = new List<T>();

                while (result.Read())
                {
                    entities.Add(map(result));
                }

                return entities;
            }
        }
    }
}
```